# lab exercises on Single node hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop, flume, oozie

I've setup a Single node hadoop cluster node cluster using cloudera's vm and needed to give examples on the below as part of lab exercise, Please help to point to some of the use case of examples that I could use to run the lab exercises on the below topics

**1 Running Sqoop Import and

2   Sqoop Export

3   Creating Hive tables directly

4   from Sqoop

5   Creating Hive tables

6   Querying Hive tables

7   Running an Oozie workflow

8   Analyzing twitter data using

9   Flume**

Answer (score 0):

Well since hadoop is a great tool to do log analysis, here's what you can do about sqoop import (and maybe querying it with hive):
Many companies are stocking a lot of logs since a lot time, but it appears that the more time passes, more and more king and number of logs has to be stored. Now Mysql/oracle can't do it anymore, so here comes the sqoop import. After that, you can continue with your usual SQL queries on your log but with Hive.
Hope this example helps !